# Cmd+K not working in Notes since Sonoma

Tags: notes.app

I use Cmd+K to create hyperlinks in my Notes app often. I notice after upgrading to Sonoma, it stopped working about 80% of the time.

Now when I press Cmd+K, it opens the dialog, and when I paste the link and press enter it does not save the link. The text remains as plaintext.

I have to repeat this process 4 or 5 times until the link actually gets saved.

[image]

Comment: what version of Notes do you have

Comment: If you click the OK button, does it work any more reliably?

Comment: @MarcWilson it is the same behavior with pressing Enter key and manually pressing the OK button

Comment: @Ruskes Version 4.11 (2463)

Comment: I have Version 4.9 (2010) and it works with that one, unless your Cmd+K is disabled or assigned to something else ....check in keyboard shortcuts

Comment: @Ruskes I don't think Cmd+K is disabled or assigned to something else, because Cmd+K works just fine, it opens the dialog. The problem here is that the dialog does not close and submit the URL back to the text properly.